# How is the Df computed in a mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, mathematical-statistics, degrees-of-freedom

The following is the output for a mixed model example. The only difference between fm1 and fm2 is the random factor "URBAN", why the df for fm2 is 5 but not 4? Any help would be great.

```
> anova(fm.null, fm1, fm2)
Data: example
Models:
fm.null: SCIENCE ~ 1 + (1 | GROUP)
fm1: SCIENCE ~ URBAN + (1 | GROUP)
fm2: SCIENCE ~ URBAN + (URBAN | GROUP)
        Df AIC BIC logLik Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
fm.null 2 644.17 650.32 -320.08
fm1     3 505.37 514.60 -249.69 140.79 1 < 2.2e-16 ***
fm2     5 423.22 438.60 -206.61 86.15 2 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: You are asking a very "deep" question actually! Determining the DF in a mixed model is always... *interesting*. Can you tell the the number of levels your factor variables `URBAN` and `GROUP` have? I am pretty sure that is related to your question... Here's a famous take on your general question: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html

Comment: Although Guess Gucci phrased this as being about degrees of freedom, they really only seem to be asking about the number of parameters in the model, and not the much trickier question related to testing the fixed effects in a given model.

Comment: @Jake, although there is an argument to be made that what you suggest is what the question is *really* about, the OP clearly conceives of this question in terms of why the df shows up the way it does. (+1 below, btw.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you move from fm1 to fm2, you are actually adding 2 additional parameters, not just 1. The "(URBAN|GROUP)" syntax says not only to add both a random intercept and a random URBAN slope, but also to estimate the covariance between these two random effects, which entails an additional parameter.

To add a random intercept and a random slope, but no covariance parameter, use the syntax "(1|GROUP) + (0+URBAN|GROUP)".

See the following section of the R-sig-mixed-models mailing list FAQ for more details:
[Model specification etc.](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#toc27)

Comment: Thanks. However, how should we count the number of parameters in a mixed model? For example, I thought there were 4 parameters for fm2; why the answer is actually 5?

Comment: The parameters are: (1) fixed intercept, (2) fixed URBAN slope, (3) variance of random intercepts, (4) variance of random URBAN slopes, (5) covariance between random intercepts and random slopes.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the example on my mixed model "mixed <- lme(GPA~1+Age, random=~1+Age|Level, method="ML", data=mydata)." However, the DF counted for the model was 6 but not 5. The null model' DF was incorrect either; I got 3 but not 2 (mixed <- lme(GPA~1, random=~1|Level, method="ML", data=mydata).

Comment: I see that you switched from lmer() in the lme4 package to lme() from the nlme package. I believe the difference in number of parameters here is due to differences in whether the residual variance is being counted as a parameter of the model. It appears that the nlme() counts this as a parameter while lmer() does not. This is confusing as sources I have found online state that lme() counts the residual variance as a parameter, but if so we would expect p=6 in that model. I have assumed that the models in the OP are normal models (i.e., not family=binomial or family=poisson), is this true?

Comment: The sources that I mentioned are:
http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#toc10 (final bullet point in this section)
https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q3/019121.html (final paragraph)

Comment: 2 comments up I meant to say: "sources I have found online state that *lmer()* counts the residual variance as a parameter..." (change in italics)

Comment: Thanks again for your explanations. I think there is something wrong with the example. I just used "lmer()" to run my models again and then used "anova()" to get DF's for them. It turned out that the DF's for my models under "lmer()" and "lme()" were identical. So I think the example may have some kind of problem.